# Filter out tickets by event_id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to filter out all the tickets to a corresponding `event_id`.
When you create a ticket (that happens inside the clicked on event, which has an id), 
it adds all the values to the database plus the `event_id` you're inside of.

Inside the event component, I map over all the tickets in the database 
and I want to filter out the tickets to the corresponding event (i.e display only the tickets that have the clicked on events Id)

but when I try to  `--(console.log(tickets.events)--` the events object inside the tickets array, 
it returns undefined.
The image displays the `--console.log(tickets)--`

[![Console and State][1]][1]
[image]

my code

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAllTickets, getTicket, addTicket } from "../../actions/tickets";
import { getCurrentUser, getUsers } from "../../actions/users";
import { getAllEvents, getEvent } from "../../actions/events";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";



class TicketsList extends PureComponent {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getAllTickets();
    this.props.getAllEvents();
  }

  getTicket(ticketId) {
    this.props.getTicket(ticketId);
  }
  getEvent(eventId) {
    this.props.getEvent(eventId);
  }

  getCurrentUser(userId) {
    this.props.getCurrentUser(userId);
  }

  addTicket = ticket => {
    this.props.addTicket(ticket);
  };

  render() {
    const { tickets, events, authenticated } = this.props;
    const ticketsList = tickets.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.id - b.id;
    });

    if (!authenticated) return <Redirect to="/login" />;

    console.log(tickets[0].events);

    return <div>
        <Paper className="styles" elevation={4}>
          <h1>Available Tickets</h1>

          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Description</th>
              <th>events id</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {ticketsList.map(ticket => <tr key={ticket.id}>
                  <td>
                    <Link className="link" to={`/tickets/${ticket.id}`} onClick={() => this.getTicket(ticket.id)}>
                      {ticket.users.firstName}

                    </Link>
                  </td>

                  <td>€{ticket.price}</td>

                  <td style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>
                    {ticket.description}
                  </td>
              <td style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>
                {ticket.events.id}
              </td>

                  <td />
                </tr>)}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Link className="link" to={`/addTicket`}>
            ADD TICKET
          </Link>
        </Paper>
      </div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    tickets: state.tickets,
    ticket: state.ticket,
    authenticated: state.currentUser !== null,
    users: state.users === null ? null : state.users,
    events: state.events,
    event: state.event
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    getAllTickets,
    getTicket,
    addTicket,
    getCurrentUser,
    getUsers,
    getAllEvents,
    getEvent
  }
)(TicketsList);
```

The strange thing is I can access the user's object inside of the tickets array and display the author's name, but anything related to events return undefined.

When I add

```
<td style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>
            {ticket.events.id}
          </td>
```

Inside the map function, it does render the corresponding `event_id`.

Comment: How are you accessing your Database? Just wondering if this is an asyn operation and are you using thunk. Also, try setting initial state in the reducer so the ticket is not undefined.

Comment: yes I'm using Redux-thunk
I access the database with endpoints in the actions.

the initial state in the ticket reducer ( GET_ALL_TICKETS )  is an empty array.
the initial state in the ticket reducer is ticket ( which is a constant name for an empty object) and that receives and dispatches the payload of GET_TICKET and ADD_TICKET

Comment: I can add my ticket reducers
and actions (endpoints for the tickets)

and yes to your question if this is an async operation, 
I am learning about async programming.

Answer (score 1):

`tickets` is an array, so events are linked to a specific `ticket`. You have to access it this way for the first ticket : `tickets[0].events`. 
The resulting console.log is : `console.log(tickets[0].events)`

Comment: I tried that,
but it returns
TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined

Comment: while `console.log(tickets)` returns the array.

Comment: It is really weird. According to the screenshot of the Chrome console tickets is an array of objects, and tickets[0].events is the way to display it. You said at the end of your question that you "can access the users object inside of the tickets array". Is it with console.log(tickets[0].users) ?

Comment: In your code, if you replace {ticket.users.firstName} by {ticket.events.name}, is something displayed ?

Comment: yes, when I do 
`{ticket.events.name}` or id it displays the right data
also when I `console.log(tickets[0])` it displays the right ticket

Comment: but when I try tickets[0].events it returns the  TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined

Comment: same for tickets[0].users

Comment: If console.log(tickets[0]) displays the ticket, console.log(tickets[0].events) should work and display the events of this ticket. Are you sure you write it well ? Where is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined" displayed ? in the Chrome console at the line corresponding to console.log(tickets[0].events) ?

Comment: inside the render() 
I write 
`console.log(tickets[0].events)`

Comment: I updated the code with  `console.log(tickets[0].events)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176352/discussion-between-newdev-and-xavierbrt).